# SymPy Liveの和集合unionの正しい使い方を教えて下さい。

Tags: sympy

https://live.sympy.org/

```
入力1
print( FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B").union(FiniteSet()))
出力1
FiniteSet(A, B, C, D, G)

入力2
print( FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B").union)
出力2
<bound method FiniteSet.union of FiniteSet(A, B, C, D, G)>
```

Comment: `help(FiniteSet.union)` を実行すると、`union(self, other): Returns the union of 'self' and 'other'.` と表示されますので、例えば `FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B").union(FiniteSet("F", "G"))` とします。また、`As a shortcut it is possible to use the '+' operator` とも書かれていますので、`FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B") + FiniteSet("F", "G")` としても同じです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help(FiniteSet.union)` を実行すると、`union(self, other): Returns the union of 'self' and 'other'.` と表示されますので、例えば `FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B").union(FiniteSet("F", "G"))` とします。

また、`As a shortcut it is possible to use the '+' operator` とも書かれていますので、`FiniteSet("A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "B") + FiniteSet("F", "G")` としても同じです。

<sub>-- この回答は [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72753/sympy-live%E3%81%AE%E5%92%8C%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88union%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%84#comment80791_72753)を元にコミュニティ wiki の回答として再投稿するものです。</sub>